# How to reorder pixels

Tags: python, image-processing

I have searched on Google but I couldn't find anything.

I want to create a Python script that can import an image, change the order of pixels, and save an output image.

I have worked with Python a lot, but only with the built-in libraries. So if I have to use new commands, please describe it as much as you can.

Comment: What image format do to have in mind? What do you mean by "change the order of a pixel"? Does something like http://www.imagemagick.org or http://www.graphicsmagick.org do what you are looking for? (Look for comparisons via Google, they are forks).

Comment: I don't have specific format. I can use anything. When I said "change the order of a pixel" I mean, if pixel 1 is on position 1 and pixel 2 is on position 2, then change their positions and have pixel 2 on position 1 and pixel 1 on position 2. Like shuffling all the pixels.

Comment: Any specific shuffling? There are many, many reorderings possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
import sys
import random
from PIL import Image

BLOCKLEN = 64 # Adjust and be careful here.

img = Image.open(sys.argv[1])
width, height = img.size

xblock = width / BLOCKLEN
yblock = height / BLOCKLEN
blockmap = [(xb*BLOCKLEN, yb*BLOCKLEN, (xb+1)*BLOCKLEN, (yb+1)*BLOCKLEN)
        for xb in xrange(xblock) for yb in xrange(yblock)]

shuffle = list(blockmap)
random.shuffle(shuffle)

result = Image.new(img.mode, (width, height))
for box, sbox in zip(blockmap, shuffle):
    c = img.crop(sbox)
    result.paste(c, box)
result.save(sys.argv[2])
```

Example input, `BLOCKLEN = 1`, `BLOCKLEN = 64`, `BLOCKLEN = 128`:

[image] [image] [image] [image]

Answer (score -1):

You should look for the PIL library [link](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)